# End notes in Memoir without any chapter formatting

Tags: sectioning, memoir, endnotes

I'm using the Memoir package and trying to setup a page of endnotes that only features a continuous list of endnotes and nothing more. In the following MWE a second chapter header (in addition to the Notes chapter head) is printed along with a subheading for each chapter separating the endnotes.

How can I eliminate both of those features?

Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}
\makepagenote
\begin{document}
\chapter*{chapter 1}
blah blah\pagenote{lorem ipsum 1}
\chapter*{chapter 2}
hah hah\pagenote{lorem ipsum 2}
\chapter*{notes}    
\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to delete the `\chapter*{Notes}` line in your MWE and add three items after `\makepagenote`, as

```
\makepagenote
\continuousnotenums % continuous numbering, not per chapter
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{} % no subheads in the Notes
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}} % just Notes heading (no Chapter)
```

For more information on the above see the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) **17.4 Endnotes**

Comment: Thanks so much! I think this is just about perfect.